# I'd like to create a reactive filter for textbox input - best practice?

Tags: meteor

I have a list of company names I'm populating from a collection 
the helper function I have is:

```
Template.companyList.helpers({
    companies: function () {
      return Companies.find({owner: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {a: 1}, name:1, createdAt:1});
    }
  });
```

- It's looped through using a

  {{#each companies}}

which outputs

```
<LI> Company Name </LI>
```

Above this I have a text box, and would like to filter the list of companies by what I type in the textbox - I'd prefer to have a *"containing"* filter as opposed to *"starting with"* filter, but i'll take either one - is there an established way of doing this in Meteor? If not, is there a plugin that someone wrote that does this?

Also, whatever answer you give, please consider the fact that I've been using Meteor for, oh, 5 days now, and i'm still learning it, so, a Newbie style answer would be great.

Thanks for Reading!

---

edit

---

This is the updated answer I came up with - combining David's answer with my previous companies helper:

```
Template.companyList.helpers({
companies: function () {
    var query = Session.get('query');
    selector = {owner: Meteor.userId()};
    options = {sort: {a: 1}, companyName:1, createdAt:1};
    if (query && query.length) {
        var re = new RegExp(query, 'i');
        selector.companyName = re;
    }
    return Companies.find(selector, options);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the outline for a simple search-as-you-type interface:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  companies: function() {
    // build a regular expression based on the current search
    var search = Session.get('search');
    var re = new RegExp(search, 'i');

    selector = {owner: Meteor.userId()};

    // add a search filter only if we are searching
    if (search && search.length)
      selector.name = re;

    options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}};
    return Companies.find(selector, options);
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'keyup #search': function() {
    // save the current search query in a session variable as the user types
    return Session.set('search', $('#search').val());
  }
});
```

This assumes:

- You are trying to search `Companies` by name.
- You have an input with an id of `search`.

Please modify as needed for your use case. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: ok, this makes sense, except for one thing - how do I point the results from this to the previously mentioned -already created list, and replace it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `companies` is a helper which returns a collection cursor. Your template is iterating over `{{#each companies}}` so all of the companies matching your query should be rendered to the template. What am I missing?

Comment: well, i already have a helper called companies, that's bringing in ALL the companies - I'm not sure how to incorporate the initial "view all" with the now changed results set.. - I hope that makes sense.. Thanks for helping! I added that helper function into my question...

Comment: Give the updated answer a try. FYI: your options in the original question don't make sense - are you trying to limit the fields to `name` and `createdAt`?

Comment: perhaps I'm not understanding you - are you saying replace my companies helper with yours? I tried that, and of course, the list is empty to start with - I'd like the list to show all on load, and filter the list as i type.. and, for the list itself, all i need is the name and createdAt fields, which is why i limited it to it. no need for any other info at that point.

Comment: I updated the answer with a check to make sure the user has typed something, and yes you should replace your helper with one like my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74149/discussion-between-raingod-and-david-weldon).